# Will the android server address for my local server(wamp) change?

Tags: php, android, wamp

I have set up a wamp server, but i have changed the port to 82 since 80 was already used by something else. Now i have an android app which takes the server address as 10.0.2.2. I have put the address as this. But this doesn't work. Will the server address have to be changed due to changed port number. If yes, then what will be the correct address through which I can access my php files.

Comment: No. If you change the port you do not have to change the ip of course. 10.0.2.2 can only be used if your client runs on an emulator. Why did you not mention the emulator?

Comment: the port number has to be added. It worked finally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the port in adress

```
URL url = new URL("10.0.2.2:82");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
```

You should have read about the networks before you start programming...